# f:actionListener for h:dataTable data

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, managed-bean

I have written a jsf form for save and listing data.For calling two methods in a button,I used f:actionListener.Data is saving but I can not any data on h:dataTable.Here is my codes.

index.xhtml

```
 <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" border="0">
            <h:outputText value="Personel adı"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{kmb.personelad}" size="25" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Lütfen personel adını giriniz!"
                         id="personeladi"/>
            <h:message for="personeladi" style="color: red"/>
            <h:outputText value="Personel soyadı"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{kmb.personelsoyad}" size="25" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Lütfen personel soyadını giriniz!"
                         id="personelsoyadi"/>
            <h:message for="personelsoyadi" style="color: red"/>
            <h:outputText value="Personel görevi"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{kmb.personelgorev}" size="25" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Lütfen personel görevini giriniz!"
                         id="personelgorevi"/>
            <h:message for="personelgorevi" style="color: red"/>
            <h:outputText value="Personel e-postası"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{kmb.personeleposta}" size="25" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Lütfen personel epostasını giriniz!"
                         id="personeleposta"/>
            <h:message for="personeleposta" style="color: red"/>
            <h:outputText value="Personel maaşı"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{kmb.personelmaas}" size="25" required="true"
                         requiredMessage="Lütfen personel maaşını giriniz!"
                         id="personelmaasi"/>
            <h:message for="personelmaasi" style="color: red"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Kaydet" action="#{kmb.veriEkle}" id="kayit">
                <f:actionListener type="com.mesutemre.ListeleManagedBean"/>
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value="Temizle" type="reset"/>
            <h:outputText value=""/>
            <br/><br/>
            <h:dataTable value="#{lmb.liste}" var="l" border="1" id="tablo">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">PERSONEL ADI</f:facet>
                        #{l.ad}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">PERSONEL SOYADI</f:facet>
                        #{l.soyad}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">PERSONEL E-POSTA</f:facet>
                        #{l.eposta}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">PERSONEL GÖREVİ</f:facet>
                        #{l.gorev}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">PERSONEL MAAŞI</f:facet>
                        #{l.maas}
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:messages  globalOnly="true" style="color: red"/> 
    </h:form>
```

ManagedBean is here;

```
public class ListeleManagedBean implements ActionListener {

private List<Personel> liste = new ArrayList<Personel>();
private MySQLBaglantisi msb = new MySQLBaglantisi();

public List<Personel> getListe() {
    return liste;
}

public void setListe(List<Personel> liste) {
    this.liste = liste;
}

public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    msb.baglan();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM jsfapp.personel";
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) msb.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            liste.add(new Personel(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2),
                    resultSet.getString(3), resultSet.getString(4), resultSet.getString(5)));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(liste.get(i).getAd());
    }
}
```

}

Why can't I see any data on h:dataTable?

Comment: Where are you invoking `processAction` from? Please, provide tested code and not a modified snippet.

Comment: I am invoking here                                     <h:commandButton value="Kaydet" action="#{kmb.veriEkle}" id="kayit">
                <f:actionListener type="com.mesutemre.ListeleManagedBean"/>
            </h:commandButton>

Comment: That doesn't seem to be invoking `processAction`...